# javascript:popWin un-encodes my URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add social sharing buttons to a website I manage. I have to use a new tab or popWin to do this as most of the social sites prevent being loaded via iframe (which prevents the use of modal popups).

I settled on popWin because it would keep the user on my page. The problem is that I'm still new to javascript and am not overly familiar with popWin. popWin appears to be un-encoding my URLs which works with most social sharing sites but tumbler has a problem with it.

If I remove popWin the URL opens a new tab and shares the product page as it should.

Can I force popWin to use my URL as is "url=http%3A%2F%2F" instead of "url=http://"

```
<a href="javascript:popWin('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>', 'tumbler', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="Share Link Via Tumblr">Tumblr</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent` in javascript.

```
<a href="javascript:popWin(encodeURIComponent('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>)', 'tumbler', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="Share Link Via Tumblr">Tumblr</a>
```

Comment: I'm looking up encodedURIComponent to see if I can figure this out myself but using this returned Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Answer (score 0):

Found this after having the same problem with popWin and tumblr. I have modified Matt's answer to show how I did it.

```
<a href="javascript:popWin('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?' + encodeURIComponent('url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>')', 'tumblr', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" 
title="Share Link Via Tumblr">Tumblr</a>
```